# ArcGIS Pro connection to PostgreSQL Database

Tags: postgresql, arcgis-pro, error, database

I am connecting a PostgreSQL database to ArcGIS Pro and it connects but when I attempt to open the attribute table I receive a "Shape Integrity Error" and cannot view it.[image]

I am able to view the attribute table when I connect to the database through ArcMap.

Comment: Related you have bad data > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240059/arcmap-copying-features-class-to-oracle-db-fails-shape-integrity-error

Comment: Is the PostgreSQL table readable in other software (like QGIS)? Have you installed PostGIS? Does your PostgreSQL and PostGIS release match the system requirements for ArcGIS Pro? Esri historically was very picky about the precise version that it would connect to.

Comment: Release of PostgreSQL (or PostGIS, for that matter) isn't likely to have *anything* to do with a "Shape integrity error". If you've gotten that far, it really is likely to be an invalid geometry. The difference between the Esri clients is likely to be in the default SpatialReference properties, especially with respect to XY precision. Therefore, please [Edit] the question to contain the SpatialReference properties in both clients.

Comment: @Vince You are correct, getting this far means the Postgres is at least connecting. If the table has been copied using PG_Dump/PG_Restore or any other non-spatial method and contains a shape field of type PG_Geometry and the matching or more recent PostGIS isn't installed you will receive an error like this as the installed DB doesn't know how to interpret the shape, likewise if the table contains ST_Geometry and the SDE libs aren't installed (do they even still exist?). I don't know about PostGIS direct connection but SDE will not allow an invalid geometry to be inserted into the table.

Comment: If there isn't an enterprise geodatabase present (yes, the ST_Geometry libraries are still available), and PostGIS isn't installed, a Direct Connect will fail. If ArcMap does read and Pro doesn't, then we're into the arcane properties of SpatialReference objects.  PostGIS *will* permit invalid geometries (because otherwise it has no way to repair).

Comment: Postgis and Arc use different geometry engines. I have run into this problem a lot. In Postgis the geometry is valid but according to arc standards it is not. Check out postgis functions st_makevalid, st_collectionextract

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250165/arcmap-error-drawing-postgis-layer-the-number-of-points-is-l